# Storing long long values in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm working with an API that returns a JSON dictionary.  One of the keys is "Variant Hash", and the corresponding data is an integer like this: -7331108254952843887 or 6209894088655053576.  I'm assuming this is a long long value.  I'm serializing this data with NSCoder, and I'm not sure which encodeValue: method to use.  There is no encodeLongLongValue:forKey:.

Also, doing `NSLog(@"%@",returnedDictionary);` displays the entire dictionary structure, but using objectForKey: doesn't work because the corresponding value for the key Variant Hash is not an object.

How can I get the data out of the dictionary, and how should I store this with NSCoder?

Comment: What JSON parser are you using?

Comment: It's a library I found through Google, called SBJSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the JSON parser you're using, the number is being stored in the dictionary as an NSNumber, NSDecimalNumber, NSString, or NSValue. NSNumber (or NSDecimalNumber, which is a subclass) is probably the most likely, but I'd check your parser's documentation or code.

Assuming that's the case, you'd get the value as such.

```
NSNumber *numberValue = [myDictionary objectForKey:myKey];
long long longValue = [numberValue longLongValue];
```

I'd probably implement some type checking in this code, just to be safe.

NSNumber conforms to NSCoding, so you can use the numberValue instance to also do your encoding.

Comment: After coding the value to disk, and then reloading it, the number changes. It goes from the correct 19 digit number to a 10 digit integer that is not even in the same ballpark. Some of the numbers are signed, others are unsigned, but they're always 19 digits long.  What could be causing this?  It's driving me crazy

Comment: What if you use NSDecimalNumber instead? It's designed for bigger numbers. You can also try Jeremy's suggestion below.

Answer (score 4):

> There is no encodeLongLongValue:forKey:

No, but there is an [encodeInt64:forKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html) which should do the trick.

Comment: Can you explain the correlation between int64 and long long? Legit question. How do you find out how the type conversions work? It's not expressly stated in the NSCoder docs and I am paranoid and want to be sure.

Comment: int64_t and unsigned long long are both 64bit ints. You can typecast between them. int64_t is signed, but it stores the same amount of data as unsigned long long (which is essentially just a typedef of uint64_t). If you save the value of an unsigned long long to an int64_t and then back into an unsigned long long it will be the same value you started with. I tested it myself a minute ago, but verify in Xcode if you're paranoid.

Answer (score 0):

If the speed is not your critical concern, just treat it as a string and use `NSString*`.